# Advice on solving Lagrange Multiplier equations

Tags: lagrange-multiplier, constraints

I am trying to solve this equation:

Find max and min values of

$$ f(a,b,c) \left (\frac{1}{abc}\right ) $$

Subject to: $$ a^2 + b^2 + c^2 = 1\ $$

I calculated the system of equations

$$   \frac{1}{a^2bc} = 18\lambda a \ $$
$$   \frac{1}{ab^2c} = 2\lambda b \ $$
$$   \frac{1}{abc^2} = 2\lambda c \ $$

However from here I am not sure how I should proceed. Any advice on solving Lagrange multipliers in general and tips on the above equation would be much appreciated.

Comment: Are you saying that $f(a, b, c)= \dfrac{1}{abc}$?

Comment: If I may, isn't it clear that the function is unbounded in both directions? Take $b=c = \sqrt{1/2 - \varepsilon},$ and $a = \pm \sqrt{2\varepsilon/9}$, you get $1/abc=\pm\sqrt{9/2}\frac{\varepsilon^{-1/2}}{1-2\varepsilon},$ which explodes as $\varepsilon$ decays to $0$. Of course, the objective isn't even defined for, e.g., $\{a = 0\},$ so it's unclear what you're optimising, per se. Depending on how you define it, the extrema either don't exist (but the supremum/infimum is $\pm \infty$), or they do exist and are various arcs of the three ellipses of the form $\{a = 0, b^2 + c^2 = 1\}$ et c.

Comment: For the Lagrange multiplier approach: a) you have a fourth equation, namely $9a^2 + b^2 + c^2 = 1$. Using this, find a stationary point (observe that the equations  you have written imply $1/2\lambda abc = 9a^2 = b^2 = c^2$). b) But this is not enough: you need the set of 'critical points' where the function is not differentiable (and in this case, also not defined), that you also need to analyse.

Comment: You could make your life a bit simpler by finding the critical points of $(1/f)(a,b,c)  = abc$ with $a,b,c\ne 0$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From

$$
\cases{
\frac{1}{a^2bc} = 18\lambda a \\
\frac{1}{ab^2c} = 2\lambda b \\
\frac{1}{abc^2} = 2\lambda c 
}\Rightarrow\cases{
\frac{1}{abc} = 18\lambda a^2 \\
\frac{1}{abc} = 2\lambda b^2 \\
\frac{1}{abc} = 2\lambda c^2 
}\Rightarrow \frac{3}{abc} = 2\lambda
$$

and  now

$$
\cases{
\frac{1}{a^2bc} = 18\lambda a = 18a\frac 32\frac{1}{abc}\\
\frac{1}{ab^2c} = 2\lambda b =2b\frac 32\frac{1}{abc}\\
\frac{1}{abc^2} = 2\lambda c = 2c\frac 32\frac{1}{abc}
}\Rightarrow\cases{a^2 = \frac{1}{27}\\ b^2 = \frac 13\\ c^2=\frac 13}
$$